# Triangular numbers that are semiprime

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Is it trivial that the the triangular numbers that are semiprime are odd, with the exceptions of 6 and 10?

This question is related to the following two sequences:

https://oeis.org/A068443 accorcding to the comments "For n>2 all a(n) are odd'

https://oeis.org/A124000

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An even triangular number is of the form $2k(4k\pm1)$.

So, unless $k=1$, it has at least three non-trivial factors $2$, $2k$ and $4k\pm1$, and so is not semi-prime.

Meanwhile $k=1$ gives $6$ and $10$.

Comment: Thank you! Follow up question without a new posts - are there infinitely many such triangular numbers that are semiprime. I am assuming we don't know this.

Comment: Some of these involve Sophie Germain primes and Cunningham chains of the first and second kind.  As far as I am aware it is all conjecture, but plausible.  For example, apparently $p= 18543637900515\times 2^{666667}-1$ and $2p+1$ are both prime, so $p(2p+1)$ is a triangular semi-prime.